# change h1 color in css based on div class with space in it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently trying to change the color of a title by referencing a div's class.

So far I have tried:

```css
.pagetitle-title.heading {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="pagetitle-title heading">IT•ONE Method</h1>
</div>
```

And even:

```
h1 {
  color: purple; 
}
```

Comment: Either of these should work. What's not working about it?

Comment: The way you wrote it, without other code, this should work. Also, in your title you say 'based on div class' but you are styling the h1 tag class. https://jsfiddle.net/hxecbL56/

Comment: Looks like a classic case of CSS overwrite. You probably have CSS elsewhere overwriting the CSS you're trying to apply. Try and add `!important` at the end of your CSS rules. I.e. `color: purple !important;`.

Comment: Thank you @martin that worked for me, (and Mihai you are probably correct)

Comment: Alright, I'll put it as an answer. @jblaupunkt

Comment: You **must** learn to use the developer tools, otherwise any CSS problem will keep driving you mad and you will start to apply horrible solutions like using `!important` (which you should avoid at all costs).

Comment: I think you should read this article, it will give you a better understanding of why your styles are not working and will also help you see what is going on when you use the inspect element developer tool https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @jblaupunkt consider accepting an answer so that this topic can be closed. :)

Comment: @martin just closed sorry! still new to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned per my comment, it looks like a classic case of "CSS overwrite". One of the "hacks" to avoid this, is to use the CSS property `!important` to tell the browser which CSS rule is particularly *important*, and should not be overwritten.

Example: `color: purple !important;`

CSS applies the style in the fashion that it is loaded. So if you have 1 CSS file with x rules, and a 2nd CSS file with y rules, and they both target the same elements, then the CSS file that was loaded last will generally overwrite the styles of the one prior.

The order is known as the *top-down rule*, and is only overwritten by the `!important` property and *in-line* CSS. The `!Important`property will generally overwrite any *in-line* CSS.

Given the information about the *top-down rule*, and you have the means to edit the CSS and/or choose the order of how the CSS is loaded, you can make sure that you are able to apply your own CSS rules by having them load as the last included file in your project.

Example:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loadedfirst.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loadedsecond.css">'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loadedlast.css">
</head>
```

In case these 3 files have rules that applies to the same elements, the *loadedlast.css* file is the CSS that will overwrite the ones prior, except in the case of the `!important` property and *in-line* CSS. By managing the order of your CSS, you can avoid having to resort to such "hacks" as using the `!important` property.

Comment: You just seem to gloss over the whole specificity rankings.  They play a much more important role than the order of stylesheets

Comment: thank you @Pete the link you provided in the comment above was very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your link "stylesheet" for your CSS
2. Open you debug console and identify your h2 to see if CSS option are targeted
3. Try another hexa color code
4. Add "!important" after touy color code

   color: purple!important;

I see your code and it's correct method to modify this color so... Try my checklist first and give us your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid adding important as much as I can. I would just go higher up the parents and try to target the div as specific as I can. Instead, I would go

```
.container h1.pagetitle-title.heading {
    color: purple;
}
```

If that doesn't work only then I would use important.